# Convert Java Time to Project Tango Timestamp?

Tags: java, jodatime, google-project-tango

If I have a Java timestamp `(java.util.Date, org.joda.time.DateTime,  System.currentTimeMillis())`, how do I convert it to the Tango timestamp used in [Tango.getPoseAtTime](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/Tango.html#getPoseAtTime-double-com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCoordinateFramePair-) method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to convert the android timestamp to the Tango timestamp directly. The Tango timestamp is usually returned through the callback function.

One possible way to solve this is to measure a timestamp offset when the application get a Tango timestamp. This offset will be mostly accurate within the application's lifecycle, but when the Tango sensor hub restarts, the Tango time stamp clock will be reset, then the offset measured before will become invalid.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the insight.  Will you please add a code example of your proposal?

Comment: Hi Aaron, actually this method is not suggested, and it's not a good practice for Tango either. I am interested to know why you want to correlate the android time stamp and Tango timestamp together?

Comment: Similar to a GPS track log, keeping a history of location+time allows for correlation to real world actions like photos, messages, etc.